# Kernel development, memory allocator and kprintf() strange output

Tags: c, pointers, kernel

I'm currently working on a little kernel project, to learn more about system development. I'm facing an odd bug : i just made and debugged a little simple memory allocator (kmalloc() and kfree() functions only), and it works perfectly fine. When i print the addresses of the pointers returned by kmalloc(), everything works except for 1 pointer ! When i print the address of this pointer twice (with kprintf("addr = %x (%x)", i64, i64)) i see "addr = 0000 (F018)".
This is the code and the output :

[Output on QEMU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UonAu.png)

CKernel.c :

```
#include "system.h"
#include "multiboot.h"
#include "util/util.h"
#include "cpu/cpu.h"
#include "video/video.h"
#include "memory/mem.h"

void kmain(multiboot_info_t* mbt)
{
    //Current status : 32 bits, protected mode
    //init
    vga_setup();
    gdt_install();
    idt_install(); //TODO : ISRs ! (actually the only interrupt handler is a method that just print "INTERRUPT" and iret)
    cpu_detect(); //TODO : Special handle INVALID_OPCODE
    //TODO : Install PAGING //Need basic DYNAMIC ALLOCATION
    //TODO : Install KHEAP

    u8* i8 = kmalloc(1, 0);
    *i8 = 244;
    kprintf("i8 = %d, addr = %X", *i8, i8);

    u32* i32 = kmalloc(sizeof(u32), 0);
    *i32 = 12;
    kprintf("i32 = %d, addr = %X", *i32, i32);

    kfree(i8);

    u64* i64 = kmalloc(sizeof(u64), 0);
    *i64 = 29999344;
    kprintf("i64 = %d, addr = %x (%X) (%x)", *i64, i64, i64, i64);
    kprintf("%d %x %X", i64, i64, i64);

    //Install ACPI
    //Install PIC
    //Install LAPIC / IOAPIC
    //Install FPU

    /*asm("   movb $0xFF, %al \n \
              outb %al, $0xA1 \n \
              outb %al, $0x21 \n");*/ //PIC DISABLING (DEBUG)
    //asm("sti"); //INTERRUPT ENABLING (DEBUG)
    //asm("int $0x0"); //INT CALL (DEBUG)

    //print done message, to see that everything went well
    kprint("[MAIN] DONE !", 1);

    //kprintf("Lower memory : %dk (0x%x)   Upper memory : %dk (0x%X)", mbt->mem_lower, mbt->mem_lower, mbt->mem_upper, mbt->mem_upper);

    //kter_install();

    //loop infinetely
    while(1) asm("hlt");
}
```

kmalloc.c :

```
#include "../system.h"
#include "util/util.h"

typedef struct
{
    u32 size;
    u8 status;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) block_header_t;

#define KHEAP_BASE_START 0xF000
#define KHEAP_BASE_END 0xFFFF

u8 base_heap_initialized = 0;

static void merge_free_blocks();

//Possible improvements : SECURITY : ADD a MAGIC number in the header, so that free() verify that it's a valid block (and malloc too)

void* kmalloc(u32 size, u8 align)
{
    u32 i;

    if(align == 0) align = size;

    //No need to merge as kfree() did it for us, right ?
    //merge_free_blocks();

    if(!base_heap_initialized)
    {
        block_header_t* base_block = (block_header_t*) KHEAP_BASE_START;
        base_block->size = KHEAP_BASE_END - (((u32) base_block) + sizeof(block_header_t));
        base_block->status = 0;
        base_heap_initialized = 1;
    }

    i = KHEAP_BASE_START;
    while(i < KHEAP_BASE_END)
    {
        block_header_t* currentBlock = (block_header_t*) i;
        //kprintf("Looking block at %X... (addr = %X) (size = %d) (status = %s)", i, i+sizeof(block_header_t), currentBlock->size, (currentBlock->status ? "RESERVED" : "FREE"));

        //Check if the current block is free and large enough
        if(!currentBlock->status && currentBlock->size >= size)
        {
            //Apply alignment contraints
            int am = 0;
            while((((u32)currentBlock)+sizeof(block_header_t)+am) % align != 0)
            {
                //kprint("Alignment : 1B used.", 0);
                am++;
                size++;
            }

            //Recheck size after alignment contraints
            if(currentBlock->size >= size)
            {
                int oldSize = currentBlock->size;
                if(oldSize - size > 5)
                {
                    currentBlock->size = size;
                    //Split the block if it is big
                    block_header_t* newblock = (block_header_t*) (i+sizeof(block_header_t)+currentBlock->size);
                    newblock->size = oldSize-size-5;
                    newblock->status = 0;
                    //kprintf("Setting up new block at %X (size = %d) (cbS = %d)", newblock, newblock->size, currentBlock->size);
                }
                //Mark the block as reserved
                currentBlock->status = 1;
                //Return the block
                //kprintf("Returning addr %X", ((u32) (((u32)currentBlock)+sizeof(block_header_t)+am)));
                return ((void*) ((u32)currentBlock)+sizeof(block_header_t)+am);
            }
        }
        //The current block did not match, skipping to next block
        i += (currentBlock->size+sizeof(block_header_t));
    }
    //Heap is full : returning null
    kprint("[GRAVE] [ERROR] The kernel HEAP is FULL ! Returned pointer to NULL !", 2);
    return ((void*) 0);
}

void kfree(void* pointer)
{
    block_header_t* blockHeader = (block_header_t*) (pointer - sizeof(block_header_t));
    blockHeader->status = 0;

    merge_free_blocks();
}

static void merge_free_blocks()
{
    block_header_t* currBlock;
    u32 i = KHEAP_BASE_START;

    while(i < KHEAP_BASE_END)
    {
        currBlock = (block_header_t*) i;
        if(!currBlock->status)
        {
            //Joining free regions
            block_header_t* nextBlock;
            while(!(nextBlock = (block_header_t*) i+sizeof(block_header_t)+currBlock->size)->status)
            {
                currBlock->size+= (sizeof(block_header_t)+nextBlock->size);
                i+=(sizeof(block_header_t)+nextBlock->size);
            }
            i += (sizeof(block_header_t)+((u32)currBlock));
        }
        else
            i+= (sizeof(block_header_t)+((u32)currBlock));
    }
}
```

kprintf() function :

```
static void vkprintf(const char* args, va_list ap)
{
    char buffer[32];

    vga_text_puts("[KERNEL] ", 0b00001111);
    while(*args)
    {
        if(*args == '%')
        {
            switch(*(++args))
            {
                case 'u':
                    utoa(va_arg(ap, u32), buffer);
                    vga_text_puts(buffer, 0b00000111);
                    break;
                case 'i': case 'd':
                    itoa(va_arg(ap, int32_t), buffer);
                    vga_text_puts(buffer, 0b00000111);
                    break;
                case 'X': /// TODO: make it standardized
                    i2hex(va_arg(ap, u32), buffer, 8);
                    vga_text_puts(buffer, 0b00000111);
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    i2hex(va_arg(ap, u32), buffer, 4);
                    vga_text_puts(buffer, 0b00000111);
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    i2hex(va_arg(ap, u32), buffer, 2);
                    vga_text_puts(buffer, 0b00000111);
                    break;
                case 's':
                    {
                        char* temp = va_arg(ap, char*);
                        vga_text_puts(temp, 0b00000111);
                        break;
                    }
                case 'c':
                    vga_text_putc((int8_t)va_arg(ap, int32_t), 0b00000111);
                    break;
                default:
                    vga_text_putc(*args, 0b00000111);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vga_text_putc(*args, 0b00000111);
        }

        args++;
    }
    vga_text_putc('\n', 0b00000111);
}

void kprintf(const char* args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, args);
    vkprintf(args, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

I'm sorry if this is not precise, if you need more details please let me know... This problem is not really important, as it seems that the pointer has the right address, but it is just strange and i wanted to know why...
Thanks for reading !

Comment: Are you targeting a 64-bit system? Then what size is a pointer? And what size is an `int` (or `u32`)? Think about that and why standard `printf` have a special `"%p"` format to print pointers (`void *`).

Comment: Also, what is your `i2hex` function doing? What is the meaning of the last argument?

Comment: Lastly, Qemu allows you to attach a debugger to it. I suggest you do that and step through the code to see what it really does.

Comment: pointer size is 32 bits (target arch is x86), int size is 32 bits too and u8,u16,u32,u64 are unsigned 8bits,16bits,32bits,64bits values (like uint8_t, uint16_t, ...)

Comment: i don't think that this is a problem with i2hex because even when i print the address with %d it prints 0 ; the last argument is the lenght of the output (i know that is strange but, shame on me, i did not write this function like the others itoa(), memset(), and all of that kind of things that i did just read and copy/paste)

Comment: i just tested it on a real computer (that has a 64bits core i5 processor) and it prints 0 too :( ++ differences between %d, %u, %x and %p are just that you are sure to have the good size printed (ex if the pointers are more than 32bits you wont see them entirely with %d), but i know that my pointers are 32bits sized so it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, problem solved ! That was just a bug with u64 and all of my itoa() i2hex() functions : they were accepting 32 bits max, so there were still 32 bits on the buffer, that were read by printf instead of the other argument (the address) ! Thanks for your answers Some programmer dude, you led my to the solution !